# Load board from string and store in two dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm trying to store a board made up of 1's and 0's in a two-dimensional array. I'm trying to return 3 sets of 3 values into the array but it says a value is expected in csvArray[][].

I've already created a string of 1's and 0's and split them into substrings separated by "\n"

```
    int[][] loadBoardfromString(string Data)
    {
        string csvBoard = "0,1,0\n2,0,1\n0,0,1";
        string[] csvArray = csvBoard.Split('\n');
        return csvArray[][];                        
    }
```

Comment: What do expect `return csvArray[][];` to do?

Comment: Well, you would need to split your csvArray strings again, no? And then, you would need to parse the individual strings representing a number each as an integer (look up the documentation for the `Int32.TryParse`/`int.TryParse` method). By the way, a `SomeType[][]` array is NOT a two-dimensional array, it is a so-called jagged array (in other words: an array of arrays). A two-dimensional array would look like `SomeType[,]` (which is not an array of arrays, but just a single array that has two dimensions...)

Comment: Just for clarification: a `int[][]` is not a two-dimensional array - it's a "jaggard" array. If it were `int[,]` then that would be a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Kind of odd that the function accepts a parameter named `Data` and doesn't do anything with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My guess this is some sort of homework so I will try use the most basic solution so the teacher doesn't know :).

```
        string csvBoard = "0,1,0\n2,0,1\n0,0,1";
        // This splits the csv text into rows and each is a string
        string[] rows = csvBoard.Split('\n');
        // Need to alocate a array of the same size as your csv table 
        int[,] table = new int[3, 3];
        // It will go over each row
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
        {
            // This will split the row on , and you will get string of columns
            string[] columns = rows[i].Split(',');
            for (int j = 0; j < columns.Length; j++)
            {
                //all is left is to set the value to it's location since the column contains string need to parse the values to integers
                table[i, j] = int.Parse(columns[j]);
            }
        }

        // For jagged array and some linq
        var tableJagged = csvBoard.Split('\n')
                                  .Select(row => row.Split(',')
                                                 .Select(column => int.Parse(column))
                                                 .ToArray())
                                   .ToArray();
```

Here is my suggestion on how you should improve this so you learn the concepts. Make a more applicable method that can spilt any random csv no matter the size and return a two dimensional array not a jagged array. Also try to handle the case when someone doesn't put a valid csv text as a parametar into your method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need:

```
    string csvBoard = "0,1,0\n2,0,1\n0,0,1";
    int[][] csvArray =
        csvBoard
            .Split('\n') // { "0,1,0", "2,0,1", "0,0,1" }
            .Select(x =>
                x
                    .Split(',') // { "X", "Y", "Z" }
                    .Select(y => int.Parse(y)) // { X, Y, Z }
                    .ToArray())
            .ToArray();
```